# Why doesn't this debounce function work?

Tags: serial, programming, button, debounce

**Edit 2** 
I made a function that works, but I'm still confused about just one thing...

I'm very confused about how variables work in C++.

**In this program...**

```
  boolean debounce(void)
{
  static boolean buttonState=LOW;
  static boolean lastButtonState;
  boolean currentState = digitalRead(4);
  static unsigned long lastDebounceTime;
  if (currentState != lastButtonState){ //if the button state has changed
    lastDebounceTime=millis();  //reset timer
    }

  if ((millis()-lastDebounceTime) > 50)  //if 50 milliseconds has passed since last bounce
  {  
    buttonState = currentState;  //read value again now that bouncing is over

    }
  lastButtonState = currentState;
  return buttonState;
}
```

**Why does changing this**

```
lastButtonState = currentState;
```

**To this**

```
lastButtonState = buttonState;
```

**Make any difference in the program?**

When I try the latter line of code, the whole function stops working and I don't understand why.

Comment: What happens if 50ms *haven't* passed?

Comment: Using the same name for globals, locals & function parameters is just begging for confusion.

Comment: Your debounce() function is only being called every 500ms. That is probably not what you intended.

Comment: @uint128_t - Why do you say: "debounce() function is only being called every 500ms" ? I don't see that, what have I missed?

Comment: @gbulmer he edited his question

Comment: at least: static boolean buttonState;

Comment: You have declared a global 'const int buttonVal = LOW' but then using this same name to get a parameter from a function. I would suspect that the global declaration is what you are getting. At the very least, use a *different* variable name within the local scope of the loop function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This probably won't answer your question completely, but here are some notes from me:

```
buttonState = current ;  //read value again now that bouncing is over
```

This won't read the value again, it just copies `current` into `buttonValue`.

What you wanted is:

```
buttonState = digitalRead(BUTTON); // read value again now that bouncing is over
```

You have multiple issues with your `debounce` call:

- `lastTimeDebounce` is never used by your code, so it is always zero.
- `lastButtonState` will be always `buttonVal` making the debounce function useless.

Some other tips:

- Don't use the same names for parameters as for global variables:

  boolean debounce(boolean lastButton, long lastDebounce, int BUTTON)

  The global variable `BUTTON` will be **shadowed** by `int BUTTON`, essentially overriding it.
- Don't use global variables (unless you have a very good reason)

**EDIT**

I would strongly recommend writing a function that debounces only **one** pin.

Because if you want a function which can debounce any pin you would need a state variable for each pin (which needs arrays hence a lot of space).

**EDIT2**:

Here is a debounce function that should work:

```
const uint8_t PIN = 13;

/*
 * Returns debounced value for `PIN`
 */
boolean debounce(void)
{
    // Current state of the pin
    boolean currentState;
    // Last state of the pin, initial value is zero
    static boolean lastCurrentState = 0;
    // Timer
    static unsigned long debounceTimer = millis();
    // Debounced value, initial value is zero
    static boolean debouncedValue = 0;

    // We first read the current state of the pin
    currentState = digitalRead(PIN);

    // Then we look if the state has changed
    if (currentState != lastCurrentState) {
        // If it has, we need to reset the debounce timer
        debounceTimer = millis();
    }

    // Then we check if the timer has expired
    if ((millis() - 50) > debounceTimer) {
        // The timer expired so we update the value
        debouncedValue = currentState;
    }

    // Save the latest state
    lastCurrentState = currentState;

    // We always return a debounced value:
    return debouncedValue;
}
```

But always test such things with an oscilloscope, no guarantee. FYI: this is not an ideal debounce function, but it should make the idea clear.

Comment: "buttonState = current ; 
This won't read the value again, it just copies current into buttonValue." I'm not questioning that your right, but I actually copied the official arduino website when I did this. https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Debounce

Comment: The Arduino site does not make the statement that it is actually reading the pin again.

Comment: Ok I understand now. I made my code look like yours, and my function works now. Thanks for the help. Quick question though, why does "lastCurrentState = currentState" have to go outside of the if statement?

Comment: You could add an else and add it there and it won't affect the debouncing. I just put it there for convience.

Comment: Sorry maybe I'm still a little confused... The second if statement will be executed no matter what right? ( because the program can't exit the function unless 50 millis have passed). If this is true, why can't I put "lastCurrentState = currentState" within the second if statement?

Comment: The body of the second if statement will only be executed if the button state has not changed over the last 50 milliseconds. I'm not sure what you are asking but you always want the latest state in a variable to check on it later.

Comment: Glad to hear :) no problem.

Answer (score 2):

"It worked perfectly" is probably an overstatement. Yes, you saw the LED change when you pressed the button, but that doesn't mean it was getting debounced.

The problem is that you are trying to use global variables to remember the internal state of the debouncer function, and you're passing those variables into the function as parameters. In C (or C++, which is the underlying language that you're using), an assignment to a function parameter does NOT update the corresponding variable in the caller's environment. Therefore, `lastDebounceTime` never gets updated, and your `debounce()` function always just returns the current state of the button.

Comment: Beat me to it! +1 for *"It worked perfectly" is probably an overstatement. Yes, you saw the LED change when you pressed the button, but that doesn't mean it was getting debounced.*. A quick (possible) fix is to remove the parameters to `debounce()` and keep the state in global variables. A bit messy, but more useful than broken.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Dave, I think I'm starting to understand. But quick question, what do you mean by "an assignment to a function parameter does NOT update the corresponding variable in the callers environment"? Does this mean assigning a variable to a function parameter is pointless?

Comment: No, it isn't entirely pointless, because you can use it as an additional local variable inside the function. You can think of it as the caller initializing that variable for you, but then you can update it as needed while the function executes.

Comment: @gbulmer or use `static` variables private to `debounce()`

Comment: @Jasen - Yes, that would be better. C++ classes are a bit verbose (I like to write Go) but a simple class would do, or a struct if there were several buttons to handle.

Answer (score 1):

Im not an expert of C programming, but I can see lot of troubles in your programming, because you do call a function debounce(), but it is not a function that does a complete task, so you set additional variables outside of it. This is a bad practice, because you can't call the same function to compute multiple keys, that's what functons are for - make one function and call multiple times with different parameters. You should switch to pointer orented parameters for lastButtonState.

```
    boolean LastButton_1; // global or static variable
    long LastDebounce_1;
    int BUTTON_1;
        ... and so on



    boolean debounce(boolean *LastButton, long *LastDebounce, int BUTTON)
        {
          //your code here, where you read and write to variables located at pointer
           boolean something, new_value;
           something = *LastButton; //read value at pointer address
           *LastButton = new_value; //store the value at pointer address
        } 
//now you call this
debounce(&LastButton_1, &LastDebounce_1, BUTTON_1)
```

Perhaps it is not correct, since I know only very basic C, but the way is the right one

Answer (score 0):

If you only have one button to debounce, you can store it's state as
static variables in the `debounce()` function itself, like:

```cpp
bool debounce()
{
    const int pin = 4;
    static bool last_state;
    static unsigned long last_change;
    unsigned long now = millis();

    if (now - last_change > 50) {
        bool state = digitalRead(pin);
        if (state != last_state) {
            last_change = now;
            last_state = state;
        }
    }
    return last_state;
}
```

If you may have to debounce more than one button, the cleaner way would
be to store the state inside an object, and have the debounce function
be one of its methods. That's what the
[Bounce library](https://github.com/thomasfredericks/Bounce2) does.

Comment: Strictly speaking, `digitalRead()` returns an `int` not a `bool`.